# Value is undefined when an initialized JavaScript object is accessed

Tags: javascript, google-maps-markers, capacitor-plugin

I have an object (`state.mapMarker`) where all the values in it are initialized as required by Typescript.  When I try to set the values in the object to new ones I get "undefined" as the values. Here is my code:

```js
const markerDistance = async () => {
  const pos1 = {
    lat: state.currPos?.coords?.latitude,
    lng: state.currPos?.coords?.longitude,
  };
  console.log("pos1:", pos1); // shows correct lat and lng

  state.otherPos.coords = await { ...state.mapMarker.coords }; // PROBLEM HERE
  const pos2 = {
    lat: state.otherPos?.coords?.latitude,
    lng: state.otherPos?.coords?.longitude,
  };
  console.log("pos2:", pos2); // undefined OR shows lat and lng as 0 as initialized
  state.distance = (pos2 === null ? 0 : haversineDistance(pos1, pos2));
};
```

Here's the definition of state.mapMarker:

```js
type State = {
  otherPos: {
    coords: {
      latitude: number;
      longitude: number;
    };
  };
  mapMarker: {
    mapId: string;
    markerId: string;
    coords: {
      latitude: number;
      longitude: number;
    };
    title: string;
    snippet: string;
  };
};

const state: State = reactive({
  otherPos: { coords: { latitude: 0, longitude: 0 } },
  mapMarker: { mapId: "", markerId: "", coords: { latitude: 0, longitude: 0 }, title: "", snippet: "" },
});
```

The first part works okay and pos1 values are correct.

The second part shows pos2 as undefined. If I comment out the PROBLEM HERE line then pos2 is 0, 0 as they were initialized at creation.

I have found comments that say this is a cached value which is read only and needs to be handled differently than I am doing here.  Unfortunately, nothing I've tried has worked. I hope someone can help me with this problem.

I've tried many different things, too much to list here. I expected the latitude and longitude values I have read to be used in the distance calculation function. Here is what is in the console log:

```
mapMarker
Proxy(Object) {mapId: 'GMap', markerId: '1', latitude: 32.93263087965151, longitude: -117.065581490625, title: 'Clicked Location', …}

pos1: {lat: 32.7822128, lng: -117.1864311}

pos2: {lat: undefined, lng: undefined}
```

Comment: You don't need `await` when doing `{ ...state.mapMarker.coords }`, right?

Comment: @Shri Hari The reason I'm using await is to prevent the console log from printing multiple times.  The code tips say the await has no effect but it actually does.  I'm not sure why I get multiple printing, this might be a sign of an issue that needs looking into.

Comment: I get the error "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'latitude')" when I try to print the value of latitude:

console.log(state.mapMarker.coords.latitude);

Comment: My problem was that I had the interface defined incorrectly. Now works after making this change: 
mapMarker: {
    mapId: string;
    markerId: string;
    latitude: number;
    longitude: number;
    title: string;
    snippet: string;
  };